# How to set dynamic input dependency on gradle task

Tags: gradle

I'm working on a Gradle plugin that has a task that generates compilable Java source code.  It takes as input for the code generator a "static" directory (property value) which should contain files in a special language (using a specific extent).  In addition, if a particular configuration property is set to true, it will also search for files with the same extent in the entire classpath (or better, in a specific configuration).

I want to make sure that the task runs if any of its input dependencies are new.

It's easy enough to add @InputDirectory to the property definition for the "static" location, but I'm unsure how to handle the "dynamic" input dependency.

I have a property that defines the name of the configuration that would be used to search for additional files with that extent.  We'll call that "searchConfiguration".  This property is optional.  If it's not set, it will use "compile".  I also have the property that specifies whether we will search for additional files in the first place.  We'll call that "inspectDependencies".

I think I could write a @Input-annotated method that returns essentially the "configurations.searchConfiguration.files" list.  We'll call that "getDependencies".  I think that is the basic idea.  However, I don't understand what to do about "inspectDependencies".  I could easily make "getDependencies" return an empty list if "inspectDependencies" is false, but is that truly the correct thing to do?  It seems likely that if someone changed "inspectDependencies" from "true" to "false" after a build, the next build should run the task again.

Comment: Take a look at `outputs.upToDateWhen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is tentative, but I asked about this on the Gradle Forum and Mark Viera convinced me that it really should be this simple, although it requires @InputFiles instead of @Input.  My particular method looks like this:

```
@InputFiles
def getOptionalYangClasspath() {
    return inspectDependencies ? project.configurations[yangFilesConfiguration] : Collections.emptyList() 
}
```